# Iframe how to animate with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, iframe, text, fade

*I have the next problem http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/14/ when i try to load animation for my iframe, but i don't know how to realize the fade out of the text when i click another button, and fade in text of this another button...
All i can do it's fade out and fade in like now, help me please?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#page3").click(function(event){
        $("#ifr").fadeOut('slow');
    $("#ifr").fadeIn('slow');
    });

 $("#page1").click(function(event){
       $("#ifr").fadeOut('slow');
       $("#ifr").fadeIn('slow');
    });

});
```

But look at the link first, please, because my buttons are divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thew problem is that you are executing a `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` directly after one another on the same element. I'm pretty sure that will cause some unwanted behaviors.

You might want to try and utilize the callback functions that those fades provide:

```
$("#element").fadeOut('slow',function(){
  // this function will be called as soon as the element has
  // completely faded out.

  // now we can fade it back in
  $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

References:

- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/)
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

Comment: i understand it, but i need to check if i click button 1 or button 2 to fade in or fade out texts, so , i don't know how to check it..i need fade it out just 1 time, when i click another button, if you understand me..

Comment: Hmm... I actually don't think I really understand then... I thought you were just wanting to fade the iframe in and out. Do you mean that you want to fade some additional elements as well?

Comment: yes, i mean, when you click button 1 for example, the text of previous button must fade out, and text which loading when i click button 1 fade in...

Comment: I don't see any animation or fading on the buttons... I can only see you fading in and out the iframe... I don't understand exactly what elements or text you are talking about...

Comment: yes, i know, it's a bad of jsfiddle, so, look, i have 2 html files with text, im loading them when i click buttons to the iframe, so every button has his own text, and i need to load it like:

Comment: 2 buttons, and text of the button 1 loading from the very begining(for example 1.html), when i click button 2 i need to fade out this text, and fade in the text of the button 2 ( for example 2.html)

Comment: I have everything on the example, everything is loading, but if you see a green square instead of iframe, that's mean iframe text is fade out.

Comment: i load texts from the src, as you can see)

Comment: Well.. I'm still not sure if I understand exactly what you are looking for.. Take a look [at this](http://jsfiddle.net/t74fT/26/)...

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, i think it is, but src it's not a http, it's just /1.html/ =)